# During debugging in pycharm "ModuleNotFoundError" appears

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, scrapy, pycharm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUy52.jpg)This is the first time I am debugging my code. Although pycharm successfully recommended me the name of the module, but when I debug the code it is saying module not found error. Need help

Answer (score 1):

You are launching `runner` inside the `glassesshop` directory, so from **its** perspective there is only one `glassesshop` package, not the two that are from the `eye-glasses` project's perspective

Change your PyCharm run configuration to launch in the `$PROJECT_DIR$` directory, and then the script would be `glassesshop/runner.py` or, of course, move your `runner.py` up one directory

---

While this isn't what you asked, you can also debug your spider just like normal Python code -- without involving all the Scrapy machinery -- by putting a `main` at the bottom of your Spider and running it normally; the same trick would work with `unittest` or `pytest`, if you wanted more formal verification

```py
class MySpider(Spider):
   def parse(self, response):
      pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open("a-sample-response.html") as fh:
        html = fh.read()
    req = Request(url="https://example.com")
    resp = HtmlResponse(url=req.url, request=req, body=html)
    s = MySpider()
    s.parse(resp)
```